# How to run a script from command line in DolphinDB

Tags: bash, command-line, dolphindb

DolphinDB has a console mode, which is very convenient when I'm too lazy to open the browser. But when I have a bunch of code to run, it would be better to save it to a file and execute like this:

```
> ./dolphindb awesome.txt
# or like this
> ./dolphindb < awesome.txt
# or
> cat awesome.txt | ./dolphindb
```

But none of these works, so I wonder how would I do this properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the command below please

```
./dolphindb -run awesome.txt
```